# Select all dates between two dates and display the unique count of inventory id for each date

Tags: oracle, date

Im using oracle db .I have 2 table specifically Inventory and grounding_info . Each inventory can have multiple grounding info or none. The table structure is as follows.

```
**Inventory**
Inventory_id

**Grounding_info**
Info_id
Inventory_id
Grounding_date
```

I want to get the count of inventories grounded on each date between a given date range. If no inventory grounded on a date , that date should be displayed with count 0.

I tried with the below query

```
SELECT tble.dte, 
       Count(groundinginfo.inventory_id) cmt 
FROM   atl_grounding_info groundinginfo 
       right join (SELECT To_date('2015/01/01 12:00:00 A.M.', 
                          'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1 + 
                                         ROWNUM AS 
                          dte 
                   FROM   all_objects groundinginfo 
                   WHERE  To_date('2015/01/01 12:00:00 A.M.', 
                          'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1 + 
                          ROWNUM <= 
                          To_date('2015/04/01 11:59:59 P.M.', 
                          'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss P.M.')) tble 
               ON groundinginfo.date_turned_in = tble.dte 
GROUP  BY tble.dte
```

but the count always shows as 0

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that you have some values, try this with `TRUNC`

```
SELECT tble.dte, 
       Count(groundinginfo.inventory_id) cmt 
FROM   atl_grounding_info groundinginfo 
       right join (SELECT To_date('2015/01/01 12:00:00 A.M.', 
                          'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1 + 
                                         ROWNUM AS 
                          dte 
                   FROM   all_objects groundinginfo 
                   WHERE  To_date('2015/01/01 12:00:00 A.M.', 
                          'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1 + 
                          ROWNUM <= 
                          To_date('2015/04/01 11:59:59 P.M.', 
                          'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss P.M.')) tble 
               ON TRUNC(groundinginfo.date_turned_in) = TRUNC(tble.dte)
GROUP  BY tble.dte ;
```

Comment: This actually works but to my surprise this takes a lot of time.. Took around 131 seconds to execute this query...

Comment: Apply the trunc to the selection of dates. What is the datatype of date_turned_in? How the data is stored??

Comment: The data type is Date itself. The date is stored in timestamp format. I dont see any performance change while using trunc either.

Comment: I actually tried another query for the same, but it returns only those dates which have values in it.
SELECT trunc(groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN) as DATE_TURNED_IN, count(distinct(inventory.VIN)) as row_count FROM ATL_INVENTORY inventory JOIN ATL_GROUNDING_INFO groundinginfo ON inventory.INVENTORY_ID = groundinginfo.INVENTORY_ID
WHERE inventory.STORE_ID = 13 AND groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2015/01/01 12:00:00 A.M.' ,'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') AND TO_DATE ('2015/04/01 11:59:59 P.M.' ,'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss P.M.')  GROUP BY trunc(groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN)

Comment: But this query does not return dates with count 0. This one actually executed within 0.25 sec. I need all dates including 0 count.

Comment: try left join for that

Comment: Got a solution:
SELECT tble.dte, COUNT(DISTINCT INVENTORY_ID) As cmt FROM ATL_GROUNDING_INFO groundinginfo
right join (
    SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/01/01' ,'YYYY/MM/DD') - 1 + rownum) dte FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366 AND TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/01/01' ,'YYYY/MM/DD') - 1 + rownum) <= TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/04/01' ,'YYYY/MM/DD'))
) tble
on tble.dte = TRUNC(groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN)
group by tble.dte
order by tble.dte ASC

Answer (score 1):

```
with  dates as (
select trunc(sysdate - 100) /*begin date*/ + level d 
  from dual
 connect by level +  (trunc(sysdate - 100)) < sysdate  /*end date*/) 
select d,count(object_id) from dates 
left join  user_objects b on b.last_ddl_time >= d and b.last_ddl_time < (d+1)
group by d;
```

Comment: SELECT trunc(groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN) as DATE_TURNED_IN, count(distinct(inventory.VIN)) as row_count FROM ATL_INVENTORY inventory JOIN ATL_GROUNDING_INFO groundinginfo ON inventory.INVENTORY_ID = groundinginfo.INVENTORY_ID WHERE inventory.STORE_ID = 13 AND groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2015/01/01 12:00:00 A.M.' ,'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') AND TO_DATE ('2015/04/01 11:59:59 P.M.' ,'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss P.M.') GROUP BY trunc(groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN)

This query worked fine for me.

Comment: Im using teh following query to get teh count of inventory in a following date rang. But my join condition is not working properly. So getting all count as 0. Pls assist.

Comment: SELECT tble.dte, COUNT(DISTINCT INVENTORY_ID)As cmt,groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN FROM ATL_GROUNDING_INFO groundinginfo right join (SELECT TO_DATE('03/11/2015 04:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - 1 + rownum dte FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366 AND TO_DATE('03/11/2015 04:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - 1 + rownum <= TO_DATE('04/02/2015 03:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) tble on tble.dte = (groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN) group by tble.dte,groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN order by tble.dte desc

Comment: groundinginfo.date_turned_in is always equal 'mm/dd/yyyy 04:00:00'?

Comment: DATE_TURNED_IN is of date fdatatype

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that might help speed things up a bit - although if you have a lot of data in your table, I would expect it to take a while.

```
with grounding_info as (select 1 info_id, 1 inventory_id, to_timestamp('01/08/2015 12:02:38.529343', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6') grounding_date from dual union all
                        select 2 info_id, 2 inventory_id, to_timestamp('02/08/2015 15:12:15.123456', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6') grounding_date from dual union all
                        select 3 info_id, 3 inventory_id, to_timestamp('04/08/2015 09:58:46.654321', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6') grounding_date from dual union all
                        select 4 info_id, 4 inventory_id, to_timestamp('05/08/2015 11:43:29.394502', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6') grounding_date from dual union all
                        select 5 info_id, 5 inventory_id, to_timestamp('05/08/2015 23:25:43.394502', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6') grounding_date from dual),
              dates as (select dt start_of_day, dt + 1 start_of_next_day
                        from   (select to_date('31/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') -- first day; ideally these would be paramaterised!
                                         - 1 + level 
                                         as dt
                                from   dual
                                connect by level <= to_date('06/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') -- final day
                                                      - to_date('31/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') -- first day
                                                      + 1 -- required to include the first day in the list of dates
                                ))
select dts.start_of_day dt,
       count(gi.info_id) 
from   dates dts
       left outer join grounding_info gi on (gi.grounding_date >= dts.start_of_day and gi.grounding_date < dts.start_of_next_day)
group by dts.start_of_day
order by dts.start_of_day;

DT         COUNT(GI.INFO_ID)
---------- -----------------
31/07/2015                 0
01/08/2015                 1
02/08/2015                 1
03/08/2015                 0
04/08/2015                 1
05/08/2015                 2
06/08/2015                 0
```